# A simple example for adding and removing buttons in wxpython

Tags: wxpython

I'm using wxpython.

I'd like to solve a simple problem for a GUI that consists of a button "Add", which when pressed creates a new button called "Remove". You can press "Add" as many times as you like and many remove buttons are created and added to the panel.
What I would like is for when you press one of the remove buttons, that remove button itself is removed from the panel.

The problem is when you bind a function to a button with this:

`self.Bind(wx.EVT_BUTTON, self.remove_function, button_name)`

you can't pass an argument to the function telling it which button to remove. (Or can you?)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I wrote about this topic a few years ago here:

- http://www.blog.pythonlibrary.org/2012/05/05/wxpython-adding-and-removing-widgets-dynamically/

The following example might help though:

```
import wx

########################################################################
class MyPanel(wx.Panel):
    """"""

    #----------------------------------------------------------------------
    def __init__(self, parent):
        """Constructor"""
        wx.Panel.__init__(self, parent)
        self.btns = 1

        self.main_sizer = wx.BoxSizer(wx.VERTICAL)
        add_btn = wx.Button(self, label='Add')
        add_btn.Bind(wx.EVT_BUTTON, self.add_button)

        self.main_sizer.Add(add_btn, 0, wx.CENTER|wx.ALL, 5)
        self.SetSizer(self.main_sizer)

    #----------------------------------------------------------------------
    def add_button(self, event):
        """"""
        new_btn = wx.Button(self, label="Remove %s" % self.btns)
        new_btn.Bind(wx.EVT_BUTTON, self.remove_button)
        self.btns += 1
        self.main_sizer.Add(new_btn, 0, wx.CENTER|wx.ALL, 5)
        self.main_sizer.Layout()

    #----------------------------------------------------------------------
    def remove_button(self, event):
        """"""
        btn = event.GetEventObject()
        print "Deleting %s button" % btn.GetLabel()
        self.main_sizer.Hide(btn)
        self.main_sizer.Remove(btn)
        self.main_sizer.Layout()


########################################################################
class MyFrame(wx.Frame):
    """"""

    #----------------------------------------------------------------------
    def __init__(self):
        """Constructor"""
        wx.Frame.__init__(self, None, title="Buttons")
        panel = MyPanel(self)
        self.Show()

if __name__ == '__main__':
    app = wx.App(False)
    frame = MyFrame()
    app.MainLoop()
```

You could also pass the button object around by using a lambda, inline functions or functools:

- http://wiki.wxpython.org/Passing%20Arguments%20to%20Callbacks

And here's some additional information about binding multiple widgets to the same event handler:

- http://www.blog.pythonlibrary.org/2011/09/20/wxpython-binding-multiple-widgets-to-the-same-handler/

Answer (score 1):

If your trouble is to pass an argument to the function, consider following:

`self.Bind(wx.EVT_BUTTON, lambda e: otherFunction(arg1, arg2), button_name)`

Answer (score 0):

[@Mike Driscoll](https://stackoverflow.com/users/393194/mike-driscoll) thanks for the great example. Unfortunately, it does not work correctly (anymore?) with Python 3.9.2. Your line

```
self.main_sizer.Remove(btn)
```

in the remove_button() method throws an TypeError:

> TypeError: Sizer.Remove(): arguments did not match any overloaded
> call:
>
> overload 1: argument 1 has unexpected type 'Button'
>
> overload 2: argument 1 has unexpected type 'Button'

For me, wx.Sizer.Remove() did only work with the index of the SizerItem. So instead of using

```
self.main_sizer.Remove(btn)
```

I used:

```
sizerItemIdx = 0

for sizerItem in self.main_sizer.GetChildren():
    widget = sizerItem.GetWindow()
    if widget == btn:
        self.main_sizer.Remove(sizerItemIdx)
    sizerItemIdx += 1
```

Please, let me know if there is a simpler or more elegant/Pythonian way to do this.